# Partial update overwriting nested fields in MongoDB and FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, fastapi

I have this schema

```
{
  "_id": "5060ad4b-fb4a-4a34-b44a-32e97626dc0a",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "user": {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-29",
    "name": "john2",
    "surname": "doe2",
    "email": "12345@abcd.edu.tr",
    "phone": "+012345678912",
    "age": 20,
    "gender": "male",
    "nationality": "smth",
    "universityMajor": "ENGINEERING",
    "preferences": {
      "doesMindHavingPets": true,
      "isSmoker" : null,
      "isMorning" : false
    },
    "password": "f61a20da9eaa68a9f06dbc1710b10ef0a67208b2059b1f576af6deac23c215f5"
  },
  (Other stuff)
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

What i want to do is receive a partial update request from the client side that could look like this:

```
{
    "email" : "12345@abcd.edu.tr",
    "password" : "asdfghj",
    "preferences" : {
        "isSmoker" : true,
        "doesMindHavingPets" : false
    }
}
```

So we could have the nested field *preferences* or not.

What I want is to merge the documents, I.e updating the email, password, and the preferences.
The "outer" fields update just fine, the problem is that the fields in *preferences* get overwritten

For example:

Using the past request, the document would look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5060ad4b-fb4a-4a34-b44a-32e97626dc0a",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "user": {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-29",
    "name": "john2",
    "surname": "doe2",
    "email": "12345@abcd.edu.tr",
    "phone": "+012345678912",
    "age": 20,
    "gender": "male",
    "nationality": "smth",
    "universityMajor": "ENGINEERING",
    "preferences": {
      "doesMindHavingPets": false,
      "isSmoker" : true,
      "isMorning" : null
    },
    "password": "f61a20da9eaa68a9f06dbc1710b10ef0a67208b2059b1f576af6deac23c215f5"
  }
}
```

So the *isMorning* field got overwritten. The output I want is this:

```
{
  "_id": "5060ad4b-fb4a-4a34-b44a-32e97626dc0a",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "user": {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-29",
    "name": "john2",
    "surname": "doe2",
    "email": "12345@abcd.edu.tr",
    "phone": "+012345678912",
    "age": 20,
    "gender": "male",
    "nationality": "smth",
    "universityMajor": "ENGINEERING",
    "preferences": {
      "doesMindHavingPets": false,
      "isSmoker" : true,
      "isMorning" : false
    },
    "password": "f61a20da9eaa68a9f06dbc1710b10ef0a67208b2059b1f576af6deac23c215f5"
  }
}
```

My current query that updates the "outer" fields is this:

```
update_result = await dbConnection.find_one_and_update({"_id": id}, 
        [ { "$set": { "user": { "$mergeObjects": [ "$user", new_user ] } }  } ], 
        return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER))
```

new_user here is a dictionary of the received inputs, for the above JSON request, new_user looks like this:

```
{'email': '12345@abcd.edu.tr', 'password': 'asdfghj', 'preferences': {'isSmoker': True, 'doesMindHavingPets': False}}
```

P.S: I am using FastAPI

I would appreciate any help :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to divide it to nested and not nested stages:

```
db.collection.find_one_and_update(
  {_id: id},
  [
    {$set: {
      "user.preferences": {$mergeObjects: ["$user.preferences", new_user.preferences]}
    }},
    {$set: {
      user: {$mergeObjects: ["$user", new_user_first_layer]}
    }}
  ])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Du4cnd2Hxdv)